# I want to implement lazy load for wordpress embedded videos from amazon s3 server

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, lazy-loading

I am working on a website in wordpress where I am showing no of videos on a page , I want to implement lazy load feature on that pages so that on page load only video thumbnail with link to it gets loaded and when user click on the thumbnail it will open the video in a pop up or lightbox.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried before asking for help

Comment: I am able to load and view the videos fine. I had tried a couple of plugins but these plugins need to host videos on their respective servers. I had hosted videos on my amazon s3 server account . And now I am stuck to figure it out how can I do it .Only issue is page loading time with the no of videos.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin that does that called [Lazy Load for Videos](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load-for-videos/) you could probably make an annotation for the theme's users to install this plugin when they install the theme.

Comment: but lazy load for videos plugin only works with youtube and vimeo videos not with self hosted videos